# Memory leak on reloadData UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks

I'm working on my first project with iOS and should be considered a beginner with both Objective-C and xcode.

I'm building an app which displays sets of items in which the amount can vary from 1-200 items. I'm retrieving the items from RSS feeds and parse the XML. I've been able to show the items in a UITableView without problems and it's working the way I want it to.

The app is for both the iPhone and iPad (testing on 6.1) and my goal is to show the items in a UICollectionView on the iPad and in a UITableView on iPhone. I've been able to show the items in the collectionview but when I call the reloadData method the app crashes with the following error:

"Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0,50c1ecd9)"

In my search for the answer I read that turning on zombies could help me locate the problem, it's giving me this error:

[CollectionCell release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xc177470

#  Address Category    Event Type  RefCt   Timestamp   Size    Responsible Library Responsible Caller
 1507   0x16941940  CollectionCell  Release 1   00:21.272.192   0   UIKit   -[UICollectionView reloadData]
 1508   0x16941940  CollectionCell  Release 0   00:21.275.833   0   Foundation  -[NSAutoreleasePool drain]
 1509   0x16941940  CollectionCell  Zombie  -1  00:21.279.332   0   Foundation  -[NSAutoreleasePool drain]

CollectionCell is my custom UICollectionViewCell class.

I'll provide both the code for the UITableView and UICollectionView which I think is most relevant to the source of the problem:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NewsCell_iPhone";
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
cell = (NewsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = nil;
    nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewsCell_iPhone" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

UICollectionView:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CollectionCell";
UICollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Test");
    NSArray *nib = nil;
    nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CollectionCell_iPad" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

NewsCell (UITableViewCell)

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
}
return self;
}
```

CollectionCell (UICollectionViewCell)

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    NSArray *arrayOfViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CollectionCell" owner:self options:nil];

    if ([arrayOfViews count] < 1) {
        return nil;
    }

    if (![[arrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]]) {
        return nil;
    }

    self = [arrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0];
}
return self;
}
```

I hope I've included what's necesarry to solve this problem, I'm open to any advice to improve my code.

Comment: I don't think you've included everything. Look at the error, it says [CollectionCell release] <- I see no release in your code.

Comment: I'm not releasing CollectionCell anywhere in my code, atleast not manually as I can't find a release call. My guess it has something to do with the initWithFrame method, I took it from a tutorial.

Comment: It's off, think it was that way by default and I'm not sure what the pro's/cons are of enabling it.

Comment: I believe you are missing a retain on the `initWithFrame` method of you CollectionCell :     `self = [[arrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0] retain];` On the other hand, if you are fairly new to it, and not up-to-date with memory management, you may indeed want to turn ARC on, as Lord Zsolt said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing your code, and your comment that ARC is off, the memory leak is most likely happening because you're allocating space for your objects, but never releasing it.

If you're fairly new to programming, specifically dynamic memory management, I would suggest turning ARC on so you don't have to worry about releasing objects.

Also, follow your tutorial, if it has ARC on, turn it on, if it's off, turn it off. This is because if it's on in the tutorial, it won't implement dealloc methods, which server the purpose of freeing up memory.

Comment: Thanks for the advice from both you and Nerkatel. Turning ARC on results in a load of errors since I've been (auto)releasing as it was included in other tutorials I followed. I'll turn ARC on in my next project. Nerkatel's answer solved the issue for now and I'll read some more on memory management to keep me from making the same mistake.